How do I import custom Python module into Brython?
I'm learning about Brython and attempting to make my game made with Panda3D (Python) to work
in the browser using Brython. The docs describe how to package modules that don't come with Brython using brython-cli make_package <module> . I packaged Panda3D this way and put all files into
the static folder for Flask server to render it.
enter image description here
It appears it's looking for the static files generated by brython cli in odd location (Lib/site-pacakges/... and cannot find it.
Does anyone have more experience with this and can advise ?
I tried to generate the panda3d.brython.js file right in the static folder. I figured it may make difference in relative path creation. It didn't help.
I'm expecting Panda3D module to work like any other module in Brython.

Regardless of the error itself, note that Panda3D is written in C++, so Brython will not know how to compile it into Javascript.
